# recv() recieves incorrect data

Tags: c, unix

When I trying to find a line of code and get a password (id, salt, hash) by a usual way, it works correctly.

```
struct spwd *shadow_file_line;
char *full_pass;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  shadow_file_line = getspnam("root");
  full_pass = shadow_file_line->sp_pwdp;
  printf("%s\n", full_pass);
}
```

But when I trying to do the same thing using recv(), something goes wrong.

```
char recieve_login_buffer[20];
    char recieve_password_buffer[20];

    char *send_msg_greet = "proftpd clone 0.1beta\n";
    send(new_sck, send_msg_greet, strlen(send_msg_greet), 0);

    char *send_msg_login_request = "Login: ";
    send(new_sck, send_msg_login_request, strlen(send_msg_login_request), 0);

    recv(new_sck, &recieve_login_buffer, sizeof recieve_login_buffer, 0);
    printf("Login entered: %s", recieve_login_buffer);

    char *send_msg_password_request = "Password: ";
    send(new_sck, send_msg_password_request, strlen(send_msg_password_request), 0);

    recv(new_sck, &recieve_password_buffer, sizeof recieve_password_buffer, 0);
    printf("Password entered: %s", recieve_password_buffer);

    sp = getspnam(recieve_login_buffer);
    full_encrypted_pass = sp->sp_pwdp;
    printf("%s\n", full_encrypted_pass);
```

So how I should change a word recieved by server? I don't know what server or telnet client which I using adds to a buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a practical approach. You will need to write some helper functions.

1. `recv()` does not null-terminate the data it reads into the buffer. It returns the number of bytes which were read; you need to use this value.
2. `recv()` on a stream socket does not guarantee the data will be received with the same framing as it was transmitted. In particular, it does not guarantee that an entire line of input -- or only one line of input! -- will be received. As worst-case scenarios, your application may only receive one byte of input, or both lines of input, in a single `recv()` call. You need to read data into a buffer and wait for a newline (or whatever other terminator is appropriate) before processing it.

Comment: so I need to delete the last element of recieved data?

Comment: @SemyonKotov No. Please read part 2 of my answer again, more carefully.

Comment: I solved that problem: recv() thinks that it recieves 2 byte more data than it  really does so I decided to write recieve_login_buffer[login_bytes_recieved - 2] = '\0'. So now it works. But why 2?

Comment: You haven't solved the problem. The return value from `recv()` is correct; your problem is either that you're sending the incorrect data, or you don't have a clear idea of what to expect to receive.